# why contacts length could be 0 when collision2D happens in Unity3D?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collision-detection

I made a ball with `RigidBody2d` and `CircleCollider2D` to collide with other balls with the same component, and I simply use the following snippet to check the contacts of the collision:

```
public void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
{
        if(collision.contacts.Length == 0)
        {
            Debug.LogWarning(" collision contacts length is 0 ");
            return;
        }
        // futher more code to deal with situation when contacts exists
}
```

And I found sometimes the collision could happen without contacts I mean the `contacts` array could contain 0 points.

Why does that happen?

Cause it's very important for me to find the normal direction of the collision, but without a contact-point, I could find that.

[image]

Comment: I have 3 questions for you. 1.Are you using Unity 2017.2? 2.Are you calling `Destroy` function on the GameObject this script is attached to? 3.Are you deactivating the GameObject this script is attached to with the `SetActive` function? Check all your script for these things and reply

Comment: 1, yes 2, and yes I will destroy the object the script attached to when the certain conditions meet (in the same frame no coroutine and wait) 3,no

Comment: Ok. For 2, comment the `Destroy` function call and see what happens

Comment: @Programmer I realize this may be caused by the re-entering of the collision(and `gameobject` may be destroyed when the re-entering happens), And I put a lock variable  to the script and seems has been fixed

Comment: When you call Destroy, it doesn't destroy in that frame and it makes the script to not construct `collision.contacts`. This is by design. Glad you got it fixed

Comment: thanks for your help again

Answer (score 2):

Well, it could happen if your `collision.contacts` have been garbage collected. Documentation says

> You should avoid using this (contacts) as it produces memory garbage.([Collision2D.contacts](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collision2D-contacts.html))

When you call that property, it creates a new array and populates it with contacts. After that, when you have finished your work with it, it will left for GC.

Also it recommends to use [`GetContacts`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collision2D.GetContacts.html) instead.
Take a look to [this discussion](https://forum.unity.com/threads/how-to-use-collision2d-getcontacts-instead-of-collision2d-contacts.502243/).

Comment: `collision.contacts` produces garbage because it returns array from the native code but this issue has nothing to do with garbage collection. The doc recommends `GetContacts` because it gets ride of mem alloc but that's that. `collision.contacts.Length` returning `0` is a whole different issue.